# "Avatar creation failed: Transform 'Hips' for human bone 'Hips' not found" when trying to choose Humanoid Rig for mocap animation FBX

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, animator, mo-cap

I import any dance FBX from http://dancedb.eu/main/performances

when I select the FBX in Project view and choose Rig--> "Humanoid" and then "Create from this model" for the Mocap FBX, I get "Avatar creation failed: Transform 'Hips' for human bone 'Hips' not found". 
Then if I click 'Configure', there's not any valid-looking information to map with. See: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9D5N.png

The ultimate goal is to use this mocap animation FBX on a different Humanoid 3D model (aka, map the mocap animation data onto it). But since I can't get both recognized as Humanoids or something, it doesn't seem to be workable.

Any ideas on how to move forward? Thanks.

Comment: I think the problem is not your human, but the dance fbx, as if you ask it to generate the avatar, it does, but its empty.. so the problem is that its not designed to be effected like that. so Ive no idea